# Ansible: Different variables for whole inventory

Tags: ansible

I'm trying to get it to work for more than just one host. Is it possible?

In this case it will be failing on another hosts of course, because process id would be different on another hosts.

```
  - name: Fetching PID file from remote server
    fetch: src="some.pid" dest=/tmp/ flat=yes fail_on_missing=yes
    register: result
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: Is pid_file matching process ?
    wait_for: path=/proc/{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/some.pid') }}/status state=present
    when: result|success
    register: result2
    ignore_errors: True
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here.. Why do you fetch the pidfile in the first place?

Comment: Its a sample from playbook, what i need is to know, if pid file is existing and has own running process, pid file can be staled = has not process up.

Comment: You'll probably be much happier if you write a proper init file for your process (whether that's SysV init, upstart, or systemd) and just use the `service` module to interact with it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you please have a better title and more detailed information in the content with your effort to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Formal answer to your question – to make it work on multiple hosts at once, use templated filename or `flat=no`, e.g.:

```
  - name: Fetching PID file from remote server
    fetch: src="some.pid" dest="/tmp/{{inventory_hostname}}.pid" flat=yes fail_on_missing=yes
    register: result
    ignore_errors: True

  - name: Is pid_file matching process ?
    wait_for: path="/proc/{{ lookup('file', '/tmp/'+inventory_hostname+'.pid') }}/status" state=present
    when: result|success
    register: result2
    ignore_errors: True
```

But a better way is to replace this tasks with one shell command that checks everything at once without fetching any files to ansible host.
You can also use `retry/until` clauses with commands to wait for specific command result.